# NativeScript-Vue Failed to find module

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I am following the NativeScript-vue tutorial here:

https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/

Does anyone know a solution to this error.I am using Windows pc. Calling module function i’m getting an error.How to solve

```
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err:
System.err: Error calling module function
System.err:
System.err: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "C:\Users\mertA\Desktop\firstNativeApp\first-nativescript-app\src\main.js", relative to: app/tns_modules/
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:530)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:522)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5791)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/app.js', line: 1, column: 583
System.err:     Frame: function:'t', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/app.js', line: 1, column: 161
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/app.js', line: 1, column: 538
System.err:     Frame: function:'t', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/app.js', line: 1, column: 161
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/app.js', line: 1, column: 511
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/app.js', line: 1, column: 520
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:
System.err:
System.err: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module:
```

Comment: Also would like to know. However my issue is that it cannot find the native dev tools despite them being in my package.json